# Include liquibase-changelogFile only if it exists

Tags: liquibase

I use liquibase 3.5.3 to provide a database schema, initial data and demo-data.

I have a master changelog-file and 3 files for the schema and the data are included.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                  http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="changes/db-schema.xml" />
    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="changes/initialData.xml" />
    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="changes/demoData.xml" />
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The demo-data are only used internally for developers and test/demo-systems. I don't want to ship them with the released product.But if I delete the file `demoData.xml`, I get an error because of the missing file.

Is there a possibility to fullfil this requirement without changing the master-file? I tried to use

```
<includeAll relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="changes/" />
```

but there seems to be a bug in liquibase when using relative paths.

```
Cannot find base path 'changelogFiles/master-file.xml'
```

I also know about the context-attribute in liquibase. But that's not what I want.

So, can anyone help me, please :-)

Comment: `includeAll` should work. Is `'changelogFiles/master-file.xml'` where you master xml file really is? Also, why would you not want to use context?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meanwhile I could solve it with includeAll. I had to add `.`to the classpath.

I don't want to use context, because the demo-data is only for internal use. I don't want to ship the changelogFile with the demo-data to the customer.